# May I remove the local master branch in a gh-pages branch-based submodule

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

I have a Github project in which the docs are generated automatically.
I have made a submodule of the directory that contains these docs; the submodule corresponds to the gh-pages branch (cf. http://blog.blindgaenger.net/generate_github_pages_in_a_submodule.html), which after pushing any changes results in me automatically publishing the docs online.

Assume my local git repo is in ~/project, then

```
$ cd ~/project
$ git br -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
```

Assume the submodule is at ~/project/docs/build/html, then

```
$ cd docs/build/html
$ git br -a
* gh-pages
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
```

My main question is: can I do

```
$ git branch -d master
```

without mucking things up?

A second, related question (which shows what I do not know about git yet) is whether it makes sense to let HEAD point to gh-pages, i.e., end up with

```
$ git br -a
* gh-pages
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
```

If it is possible and makes sense: what are the (dis)advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the submodule, yes you can since that will only delete it in that sub-repository.

You shouldn't push the delete to the remote `master` since that's the projects `origin/master`.

Changing `origin/HEAD` to point to `origin/gh-pages` may not be what you want. This might effect which is the default branch on github for the the project.

Comment: So I might gain some local space, but it results in having to be more careful when pushing. This means it only makes sense in a space-constrained context.